# How to forbid IE to browse a https site if the cert is not trusted?

Tags: security, internet-explorer, group-policy

I've been Googled for a while, and didn't find any easy way to do this.

Basically, I want to make sure the IE users in my network cannot browse possibly phishing site, or those are compromised with a untrusted cert. Currently they will get a cert not-trusted warning, but still able to bypass it.

I'm looking for something can be done via group policy.

Can any one help? Thanks ahead!

Comment: Which version of the browser are you using? Also, what's the operating system?

Comment: So sorry, forgot to mention, its IE9, and Vista

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no policy/option in Windows Internet Explorer that will let you do this. You could try writing a custom browser that prevents the loading of any website with an invalid certification, but this is probably a lot of effort for what you're trying to achieve.

There is a "hack" that I wouldn't recommend, but should let you customize the error pages in Internet Explorer by editing the ieframe.dll.mui file. However, you would need to do this on every PC and re-apply it when Microsoft updates that file.

If you do this you will need a bit of software called Resource Hacker, and then use that to edit the `C:\Windows\System32\en-US\ieframe.dll.mui` file. In there navigate to 
`23\INVALIDCERT.HTM\1033` and remove the `<!-- continue to site-->` segment.

Again I would not recommend this. Instead why not filter all your users web traffic through a proxy server, with a good piece of web security software to prevent the latest phishing websites.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest approach is with the perimeter firewall:

```
 Deny source destination tcp 80.
 Allow source destination tcp 443.
```

Use Windows client firewall if perimeter blocking is too restrictive.  Window firewall benefits:

- limits the outbound rule per application (i.e., IE)
- Easy GPO configuration.

PowerShell example:

```
New-NetFirewallRule -Protocol TCP -RemotePort 80 -Program “C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe” -Action Block -Profile Domain, Private -DisplayName “Block IE TCP 80” -Description “Block WWW TCP 80 from IE” -Direction Outbound
```

Additional considerations

- Microsoft EMET certificate pinning.
- Enforce Microsoft Name Resolution Policy Table (NRPT) policy to mitigate DNS poisoning and DNS MITM.
- Additional outbound rules for public and private profiles.  Only permit these profiles to connect to external company VPN or RDP gateways.
- Use proxy server that enforces 443 for your domain profile.

I think restricting all WWW traffic to 443 is a good idea.  It will not work for all situations though.  Good Luck!